# Solve for constants in rational model

Tags: rational-functions

I  have the following rational model equation which fits distance versus time data very well:

$$y = \frac{bt}{1+ct+dt^2}$$

The derivative of this equation is :

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{(b-bdt^2)}{(1+ct+dt^2)^2}$$

Now at $t = 0, y = 0$ and
$$\frac{dy}{dt} =u$$

where $u$ is the velocity at $t=0$

At $t = t_1, y = r$ and
$$\frac{dy}{dt} =v$$

what I would like to do is solve for the constants $b$, $c$ and $d$ in terms of $u$, $v$ and $r$:

I can easily get:

$$b = u$$

but I'm having trouble solving for the other coefficients.  Is it possible to solve for $c$ and $d$ in terms of $u$, $v$ and $r$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Delta := 1+ct_1+dt_1^2$.

At time $t_1$ you have $y = r$ so $\frac{b t_1}{ \Delta} = r$ and $\dot{y} = v$ so $\frac{b(1-dt_1^2)}{\Delta^2} = v$.

You already solved $b = u$. Hence, the first equation yields $\Delta = \frac{ut_1}{r}$.
Now $\Delta$ is thus known.

Substituting in the second leads to $b(1-dt_1^2) = v \Delta^2$, from which you can determine $d$.

Eventually, going back to the definition of $\Delta$ and knowing $d$, you can compute $c$.

Comment: In solving for d, I'm able to get $1-dt_1^2 = \frac{vut_1^2 }{r^2}$.  However, I can't figure out how to get rid of $t_1$, so that I can solve for d without $t_1$.

Comment: As I understood your question, $t_1$ is known. Otherwise, you have two many unknowns for your number of equations.

Comment: Since $d$ is determined by a condition involving $t_1$, isn't it reasonable to think that $d$ may actually *depend* on $t_1$? In other words, you can't get rid of it.

Comment: @MPW: Since  v is the velocity and r is the distance at $t_1$, I was hoping they might be able to serve as a "proxy" for $t_1$.  $v=ucos\beta$ where $\beta$ is a known angle.  Therefore $v$ does not depend on $t_1$.  But $r$ does except for specialized cases where I can assume it does not

Comment: Well, if you *know* that $v t_1 = u \cos \beta$, where $u$, $v$ and $\beta$ are known, then you can compute $t_1$ to "get rid of it" in the other equations.

Comment: @cs89: I know that $v=ucos\beta$ not that $v t_1 = u \cos \beta$.  However, I've tested all of my data and have found that the following approximation holds to within less than 5%:   $t_1 = \frac{2r}{u+v}$.  In other words, I can use the linear average of the starting velocity, u, and ending velocity, v, to estimate $t_1$.  I'm still checking to see what the velocity profile looks like with this assumption.